# Python: how to have both python 2 and python 3 on jupyter on mac?

Tags: python, jupyter

I am running `jupyter` on mac

[image]

If I choose python3 and I import a package that works only on python3 I have the following:

[image]

However If I do:

```
python3
Python 3.6.8 (v3.6.8:3c6b436a57, Dec 24 2018, 02:10:22) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import mgwr
```

it works fine

Comment: How did you install the `mgwr` package?  It is probably installed in your default python 3 environment, but not in the same environment as the "Python 3" kernel that Jupyter is running.  I use Conda environments, and install the `ipykernel` package in all of my environment, then use the `nb_conda` package with Jupyter to allow me to select the appropriate kernel.

Comment: I installed `mgwr` trough `pip3`. I do not have anaconda